# Salt: execute custom SQL after creating a postgres user

Tags: postgresql, salt-stack

Creating postgres users with salt works perfectly with [states.postgres_user](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.postgres_user.html)

I need to run a custom SQL to alter the user:

```
ALTER USER foo_bar_p CONNECTION LIMIT 20;
```

How can I run the above SQL after salt created the user `foo_bar_p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is untested, but I believe it will get you there:

```
postgres-set-user-conn-limit:
  cmd.run:
    - name: psql -U <user> -d <db> -c 'ALTER USER foo_bar_p CONNECTION LIMIT 20;'
    - env: PGPASSWORD='<password>'
    - require:
      - postgres_user: foo_bar_p
```

Or as @guettli suggested in the comments, a method to avoid requiring a password at all:

```
postgres-set-user-conn-limit:
  cmd.run:
    - name: psql -U <user> -d <db> -c 'ALTER USER foo_bar_p CONNECTION LIMIT 20;'
    - user: postgres
    - require:
      - postgres_user: foo_bar_p
```

Comment: Thank you, works. I used "user: postgres" for `cmd.run` this way I don't need to supply a password.

Comment: @guettli nice trick! I didn't realise that running psql as the postgres user would skip passwords..